# convert bigint date value in UTC to EST and update in onother field of same table postgresql

Tags: postgresql, sql-update

```
CREATE TABLE DATES
(
DATE_UTC BIGINT,
DATE_EST BIGINT
);
```

I have date_utc `20210217010700`, `20190211010000`,`20210111010060`....which are in UTC format

I need to convert these values in to EST format and update in DATE_EST column in PostgreSQL

Comment: That is a horrible data model. You should only store that timestamp once in a column defined as `timestamptz` then can get that at any time zone you want. Don't store information that can easily be derived from existing data twice.

Comment: we had an unique requirement ,we had to update DATE_EST data in multiple tabels, i just asked as a sample,can you please help me in way to convert?

Comment: The value `20210111010060` can't properly be converted to a timestamp (assuming that bigint is representing the date as `yyyymmddhhmiss`) because 60 seconds isn't valid for a timestamp value.

Comment: ok take 20190211010000 as example, can this be converted for my requirement?,above data is for informative purpose

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the number is actually a string that represents a timestamp in the format `yyyymmddhh24miss` and you can get rid of the invalid values (which couldn't have happened with a proper `timestamp` btw), you can do something like this:

```
update dates
  set date_est = to_char(((to_timestamp(date_utc::text, 'yyyymmddhh24miss') at time zone 'utc')::timestamp at time zone 'est')::timestamp, 'yyyymmddhh24miss')::bigint
```

Comment: the converted data seems to be in 2020-05-06 01:00:00 it is a string how can we fit it in bigint data column

Comment: Convert it back using `to_char(..., '....')::bigint` see my edit - the complexity of that expression should ring every alarm bell in your team that your choice of data types is seriously wrong.

Comment: am trying to convert in into America/Chicago timezone
20210129211500 is the UTC timezone
20210130031500 is the DATA am getting after conversion which is wrong
America/Chicago is behind UTC but it is exceeding in this case can you please help?